# Multiplayer survival on PS4?

Tags: killing-floor-2

This month, Killing Floor 2 is part of the PS+ game of the month.

I grabbed it and liked the solo play, and wanted to play survival with friends.

However, whatever options I try (public/private, all maps/selected map, difficulty...), the matchmaking server will never find a session, and it seems it doesn't create one either.

On the other hand, Survival VS work almost instantly.

How do I create a private session and play survival (not VS) with one or two friends on PS4?

Edit:
The questions is not "How do I create a multiplayer match", but why is the normal Survival mode is bugged, and if there is a workaround to this bug. Or where to find, if available, information about that bug, since KF2 website doesn't reference that bug.

Comment: I've heard that matchmaking for KF2 (at least on PS4) can be buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research on fan forums, I found out that due to the PS+ offer, the European and American servers are overloaded.
A solution proposed was to select Australian server, wich are playable, however, the ping is awful.

Comment: Which doesn't make sense because when you're playing with friends and setting the permissions to friends only you're essentially assuming control of the server and hosting. As far as I understood. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: I don't understand either why it doesn't work on private party, but well, I at least have a workaround.

Comment: @n_palum you can choose zu host  (I dont remember how the option is called) but that is not the default and even if you select it, you probably wont be able to find a server for your self hosted Lobby. As far as I know, you still use the actual game servers to host a game.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty straightforward actually.

1. Hit online matchmaking.
2. Go to permissions and hit friends only.
3. Go to the right hand side and invite, or invite via PS4 menus.

If you want a reference, watch [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niUz4kuto6Q)

Comment: That bit work well on Survival VS, and I can invite in Survival too, but the game will never start. My question was more about why the normal Survival doesn't work, and where/if there is information about how/when it will be fixed, since it seems to come from the server side

Comment: @DrakaSAN unless something has changed since I played KF2 on my PS4 months ago, this should be correct. I can go and verify this answer later if you'd like.

Comment: I'm not sure otherwise what you mean, Survival VS and Survival normal? This works for both modes